# Regarding sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed

Tags: java, github-api

I am trying to connect GitHub by using Github api and java. While connecting to github i am getting the Exception  -

```
 sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed
```

i am doing standalone app.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Check the certificate you are using for SSL, that looks like you are not using the right one (or none at all)

Comment: i am new to this,can yu please tell me which certificate i have to use  and how can i use

Comment: You need to get the right certificate out of your GIT server (github in this case).  This is easily done through your browser.  Build a keystore containing that certificate and make your java application trust it.  You will find directions to these tasks here:  http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-java-keytool-keystore-commands.html    http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php   http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbxw.html